# AdMob testing left on at launch?

Tags: java, android, cordova, admob

I've just published an Android app to Google Play. The app displays AdMob banners. I just realized that I left `request.setTesting` set to `(true)`. I know very little about the Java code used to integrate AdMob (it's a PhoneGap app). Have I left the ads in some kind of test mode? Will they not run/generate revenue? When I manually install the .apk onto my devices, the ads run just fine, but the app has yet to show up in the Play Store.

Code:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
LinearLayout layout = super.root;
layout.addView(adView); 
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(true);
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Should I change the value to `false`? Sorry for the beginner-ish confusion, but I'm not a Java genius, and this is my first time using AdMob.

Comment: settesting api is deprecated. so it should ideally be out of use in the latest admob sdks. It is better to remove the deprecated apis from the code and publish again. Just to be on a safer side.

Comment: Thanks, prijupaul. So, it shouldn't really be having any effect as-is anyway?

Comment: Ideally you should have deleted that line from your code, as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-release your app without the the call to #setTesting.